# Spring AMQP AsyncRabbitTemplate Doesn't Send Message In Delay Time

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to send delayed messages on RabbitMQ with Spring AMQP.

I'm defining MessageProperties like this:

```
MessageProperties delayedMessageProperties = new MessageProperties();
delayedMessageProperties.setDelay(45000);
```

I'm defining the message which should be send in delay time like this:

```
org.springframework.amqp.core.Message amqpDelayedMessage = org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageBuilder.withBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(reversalMessage).getBytes())
                   .andProperties(reversalMessageProperties).build();
```

And then, If I send this message with RabbitTemplate, there is no problem. Message is being sent in defined delay time.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("delay-exchange",delayQueue, amqpDelayedMessage, new ParameterizedTypeReference<org.springframework.amqp.core.Message>() {
            });
```

But I need to send this message asynchronously because I need not to block any other message in the system and to get more performance and if I use asyncRabbitTemplate, message is being delivered immediately. There is no delay.

```
asyncRabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceiveAsType("delay-exchange",delayQueue, amqpDelayedMessage, new ParameterizedTypeReference<org.springframework.amqp.core.Message>() {
            });
```

How can I obtain the delay with asnycRabbitTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug; please open an issue on GitHub.

The `convertSendAndReceive()` methods are not intended to send and receive raw `Message` objects.

In the case of the `RabbitTemplate` the conversion is skipped if the object is already a `Message`; there are some cases where this skip is not performed with the async template; please edit the question to show your template configuration.

However, since you are dealing with `Message` directly, don't use the `convert...` methods at all, simply use

```
public RabbitMessageFuture sendAndReceive(String exchange, String routingKey, Message message) {
```